# How to add a value to an object's property in LWC (Dynamic column to Datatable)

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, javascript, lightning-experience, lightning-datatable

**Edit 4**

I'm using a `lightning-datatable` implementation where I'm populating the data and columns from a wrapper Apex object properties.

Parent component call server-side method, that returns a **List** of my wrapper object:

Apex Wrapper Object:

```
public class ColumnAndDataWrapper {
    @AuraEnabled
    public List<SObject> recordList;
    @AuraEnabled
    public List<Column> columns;
    @AuraEnabled
    public String objectPluralLabel;
    @AuraEnabled
    public String iconName;
    public ColumnAndDataWrapper(List<SObject> recordList, List<Column> columns, String objectPluralLabel, String iconName) {
        this.recordList = recordList;
        this.columns = columns;
        this.objectPluralLabel = objectPluralLabel;
        this.iconName = iconName;
    }
}
```

Apex object Column:

```
public class Column {
    @AuraEnabled
    public String label;
    @AuraEnabled
    public String fieldName;
    @AuraEnabled
    public String fieldType;
    public Column(String label, String fieldName, String fieldType) {
        this.label = label;
        this.fieldName = fieldName;
        this.fieldType = fieldType;
    }
}
```

Lightning Datatable implementation

```
<template>
    <template for:each={records} for:item="record">
        <div class="slds-var-m-top_medium" key={record.key}>
            <lightning-card icon-name={record.iconName} title={record.objectPluralLabel}>
                <div class="slds-card__body slds-card__body_inner">
                    <c-icrm-rich-datatable
                        key-field={record.key}
                        data={record.recordList}
                        columns={record.columns}
                        onrowaction={handleRowAction}
                        show-row-number-column
                        hide-checkbox-column
                        enable-infinite-loading
                    >
                    </c-icrm-rich-datatable>
                </div>
            </lightning-card>
        </div>
    </template>
</template>
```

Client-side controller

> From Jake's answer, if do `record.columns.push(newCol)`, I get an error because the `record.columns` is a Javascript **Object** and not an Array/Map.

I have tried to parse the object to an array by implementing  the **Object.entries()** method like this:

```
export default class RetireContactDatatable extends LightningElement {
@api objectRecordsMap = [];
@track records = [];
    connectedCallback() {
        let _map = this.objectRecordsMap;
        let newCol = { type: 'action', typeAttributes: { rowActions: actions } };
        for (let _key in _map) {
            if (_map.hasOwnProperty(_key)) {
                let record = {
                    key: _key,
                    iconName: _map[_key].iconName,
                    objectPluralLabel: _map[_key].objectPluralLabel,
                    recordList: Object.entries(_map[_key].recordList),
                    columns: Object.entries(_map[_key].columns)
                };
                record.columns.push(newCol);
                this.records.push(record);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is how it looks:

[image]

From the debug console:

```
    [
    [
    "0",
    {
        "fieldName":"Name",
        "fieldType":"text",
        "label":"Grant Report Name"
    }
    ],
    [
    "1",
    {
        "fieldName":"Award_Amount__c",
        "fieldType":"currency",
        "label":"Award Amount"
    }
    ],
    [
    "2",
    {
        "fieldName":"Docket_Record__c",
        "fieldType":"reference",
        "label":"Docket Record"
    }
    ],
    {
    "type":"action",
    "typeAttributes":{
        "rowActions":[
            {
                "label":"Edit",
                "name":"edit_record",
                "iconName":"utility:edit"
            },
            {
                "label":"Delete",
                "name":"delete_record",
                "iconName":"utility:delete"
            }
        ]
    }
    }
]
```

I'd say I'm close, but as  you see the data is not rendering.

At this point I've tried several approaches and non of them seems to work as I expect.

I took another approach by using **Object.assign({}, data)** method instead of parsing, this way I should be able to update the column value.

```
connectedCallback() {
    let _map = this.objectRecordsMap;
    let newCol = { type: 'action', typeAttributes: { rowActions: actions } };
    for (let _key in _map) {
        if (_map.hasOwnProperty(_key)) {
            let record = {
                key: _key,
                iconName: _map[_key].iconName,
                objectPluralLabel: _map[_key].objectPluralLabel,
                recordList: _map[_key].recordList,
                columns: _map[_key].columns
            };
            record.columns = Object.assign(newCol, record.columns);
            this.records.push(record);
        }
    }
}
```

But this is not working either, just shows the card header with title and icon.

Comment: Did you try to update the `this.keyValue.value.columns`  instead? Probably the `keyValue` will need to be decorated with `@track`.

Comment: I don't think that could work, I tried tho, and can confirm didn't work, keyValue is the current item for the for:each directive, is not a property on the LWC, like objectRecordsMap for exmaple.

Comment: Nah, you have to just assign a totally new `columns` array (with your added values). It's not going to detect any other method of addition.

Comment: @CasparHarmer even doing that, then the data will not render, I've tried that also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the Wrapped Object has a property that is a List (of Apex object `Column`), I realized that I had to loop through that List and push each element to my LWC tmp record column property.

```
@api objectRecordsMap = [];
@track records = [];

connectedCallback() {
    let _map = this.objectRecordsMap;
    let newCol = { type: 'action', typeAttributes: { rowActions: actions } };
    for (let _key in _map) {
        if (_map.hasOwnProperty(_key)) {
            let record = {
                key: _key,
                iconName: _map[_key].iconName,
                objectPluralLabel: _map[_key].objectPluralLabel,
                recordList: _map[_key].recordList
            };
            let cols = [];
            _map[_key].columns.forEach(element => {
                cols.push(element);
            });
            cols.push(newCol);
            record.columns = cols;
            this.records.push(record);
        }
    }
}
```

Since I'm pushing values each time we loop through the list of records, the record.column would get all the columns for all the objects records (1 loop: 3 cols, 2 loop: 1 Loop. Cols + 2 Loop. Cols and so on), to avoid this, I created a temp var to hold the columns, and then set the record.columns to this array, and clean it before the next assignment.

Answer (score 3):

IIUC, you have an apex object that has a columns property, which you pass to your lwc. In your lwc, you want to add an action column for edit and delete.

Assuming your `c-icrm-rich-datatable` is extending the `lightning-datatable` component, the columns and actions property needs to look like this:

```
const actions = [
    { label: 'Edit Record', name: 'edit_record' },
    { label: 'Delete', name: 'delete_record' }
];

const columns = [
    { type: 'action', typeAttributes: { rowActions: actions, menuAlignment: 'left' } }
];
```

Note that `columns` and `actions` are arrays of objects. Each column on your table is an object which is an element in the columns array.

In your loop, you can do this:

```
let newCol = { type: 'action', typeAttributes: { rowActions: actions } };

for (let _key in _map) {
    if (_map.hasOwnProperty(_key)) {
        let record = {
            key: _key,
            iconName: _map[_key].iconName,
            objectPluralLabel: _map[_key].objectPluralLabel,
            recordList: _map[_key].recordList,
            columns: _map[_key].columns
        };
        record.columns.push(newCol);
    }
    this.records.push(record);
}
```

Check the "Creating Static Row-Level Actions" section [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-datatable/documentation) for more details.

Edit:
Assumptions:

Your Apex object Column looks like this:

```
public class Column {
    @AuraEnabled
    public String fieldName {get; set;}
    @AuraEnabled
    public String fieldType {get; set;}
    @AuraEnabled
    public String label {get; set;}
}
```

So when you do `_map[_key].columns` in your loop, it looks like this

```
[
  {
    "fieldName": "Name",
    "fieldType": "text",
    "label": "Grant Report Name"
  },
  {
    "fieldName": "Award_Amount__c",
    "fieldType": "currency",
    "label": "Award Amount"
  },
  {
    "fieldName": "Docket_Record__c",
    "fieldType": "reference",
    "label": "Docket Record"
  }
]
```

And after you do `record.columns.push(newCol);`, if you ran a `console.log(record.columns)` It would look like this:

```
[
  {
    "fieldName": "Name",
    "fieldType": "text",
    "label": "Grant Report Name"
  },
  {
    "fieldName": "Award_Amount__c",
    "fieldType": "currency",
    "label": "Award Amount"
  },
  {
    "fieldName": "Docket_Record__c",
    "fieldType": "reference",
    "label": "Docket Record"
  },
  {
    "type": "action",
    "typeAttributes": {
      "rowActions": [
        {
          "label": "Edit",
          "name": "edit_record",
          "iconName": "utility:edit"
        },
        {
          "label": "Delete",
          "name": "delete_record",
          "iconName": "utility:delete"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: you got it right, that's what I'm trying to achieve. to add a column to the datatable, tho I'm passing a List of the Apex object, instead of just one. I've tried your method before and did again just in case and it errors `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: 'set' on proxy: trap returned falsish for property '3'`. I'll update the question with new insights about my blocker.

Comment: Based on your post, the columns property in your apex object is a list. According to your post update, it's a Javascript object. For it to work with the lightning-datatable, it needs to be a list of objects like I showed in my answer. I've added some sample json based on what you've shown.

Comment: I get this error: `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: 'set' on proxy: trap returned falsish for property '3'` because I'm trying to push a value to an Object, for the case of the column.